# how to implement "cumdot" in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two 1d arrays with same length(saying n),and now I want to implement a "cumdot" function,which output 1d array with length n and can be implemented in pure python code

```
def cumdot(a,b):#a,b are two 1d arrays with same length
    n = len(a)
    output = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        output[i] = np.dot(a[:i+1],b[:i+1])
    return output
```

How can I implement the "cumdot" function more efficiently?

Comment: When you say "pure python" code, obviously you mean with numpy as well, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def cumdot(a, b):
    return numpy.cumsum(a * b)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think by *pure python* you mean: using core of python!

```
def comdot(a, b):
    result = [i[0]*i[1] for i in zip(a, b)]
    return result
```

Comment: What is the reason for down voting? My code solves the problem, doesn't it?